# facebook app with no negative feedback marked as spam

Tags: facebook

i'm an indie dev who has been testing their app/game over the past two weeks and published a total of 4 times. it will no longer allow me to change the Canvas and Secure Canvas URL stating that they are not valid, i have been using googledrive

the last time i attempted to test to make sure none of the changes had broken the facebook prompt to post to wall share button it told me the app had been marked and that i could file a report but this may or may not change anything. there is no negative feedback the only thing i've done is delete the test posts after a day or so.

is there a way to get my app or "my" website unmarked as spam? how long does it take them to review it? or would just creating a new test app solve the canvas URL problem?

thanks!

Comment: host your App in Heroku . The links will be valid .

Answer (score 0):

Try putting your app in Sandbox mode. This will not unmark your app as spam, but it will allow you to continue development/testing.